# how to enable / disable IE proxy setting programatically?

Tags: c#

I want to Enable / Disable the proxy for my Internet Explorer programatically - C#
Can some one help me on this regard?

Thanks in advance,
Ravi Naik.

Answer (score 6):

```
RegistryKey registry = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", true);            

//disable proxy           
registry.SetValue("ProxyServer", 1);

//remove tik 

    registry.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 0);

//Proxy Status

    int proxyStatus = (int)registry.GetValue("ProxyEnable");
    if (proxyStatus == 0)
        lblProxyStatus.Text = "disable ";
    if (proxyStatus == 1)
        lblProxyStatus.Text = " enable";
```

Comment: Is there anyway to change Proxy without changing Registry?